# SQL Server missing index in execution plan

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have created a view which contain 50 joins and some correlated subqueries.

When I am trying to look at the execution plan, it is not recommended missing index.

Could you please let me know why SQL Server is not showing any missing index statements for the running statement?

Comment: Maybe because there are just no missing indexes that could help this view .....

Comment: Sounds like something the Database Tuning Advisor would be better suited for anyway as that can do more exhaustive "what if" analysis.

Comment: Perhaps you could tell us if you experience any performance problems first? And if so, explain why there is a need for 50 joins and correlated subqueries. Perhaps it is easier to write several views instead of just one? You could then join those views if needed rather than have one grand view that has it all...

Comment: Hello TT, thanks alot for replying. I have no experience om performance.please suggest me some alternatives that would help to improve the performance

Comment: An alternative could be not to do 50 joins and correlated sub-queries in a view (sounds like a 'one size fits all' query) - but otherwise, nobody can help you without information.

Comment: Hello marc, thanks for replying. I am surprised to see such behaviour of sql. There is no indexing on these. I have created few index today. After creation of index it just imorove the performance by 20 mins. Earlier it was taking 1 har 10 min.. now it is taking 50 mins only. That is the reason, i am worried about missing index.

Comment: Thanks Allan for quick response. If we use multiple views insted of one view. Would it be help?? And we are doing the conversation of data type in select statement. Is it impact the huge performance?

Comment: hello Martin Smith, Thanks for replying. I will try with tuning advisor also and will let you know if get some successful :)

Comment: a view with 50 joins sounds excessive, can you show a cut down sample of your table structures. Your not implementing a one table to rule them all approach are you - see http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/58372/is-the-one-description-table-to-rule-them-all-approch-good

Answer (score 0):

Here is my understanding. SQL is declarative language.
It means you only need to specify what data you want and from where you want it.
The rest is the task of server to do.
SQL server is using CBO (cost based optimizer) engine to determine which access method should be used. If you use select * from tablename without where it will be not used any index.
Index while increasing performance on certain case, it will be hindrance.
SQL uses the statistics to determine which access method will be used. Index seek, index scan, cluster index seek, cluster index scan etc. 
So to answer your question is probably because of :
1. the statistics is not updated
2. you use select without where
3. your database is fit in memory so no index will be used